# How to make an equal distribution of turtles for each profile type using NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I have no idea how to solve the following problem:

I have 9 turtle profiles which are:

profile1: M1R1
profile2: M1R2
profile3: M1R3
profile4: M2R1
profile5: M2R2
profile6: M2R3
profile7: M3R1
profile8: M3R2
profile9: M3R3

M= metabolism and R = reproduction.

I would like the world to have an exact number of turtles born in each of these profiles. For example:

profile1: 2 turtles
profile2: 2 turtles
profile3: 2 turtles
profile4: 2 turtles
profile5: 2 turtles
profile6: 2 turtles
profile7: 2 turtles
profile8: 2 turtles
profile9: 2 turtles

It turns out that I'm just getting to have variable numbers between the profiles. is it possible for me to distribute exact amount of turtle breeding for each profile? If yes, could anyone suggest some sort of solution? Well, I've been trying to solve this for a long time!!! :)

Thanks in advance

```
globals [ AvailablePatch ]

turtles-own [ metabolism reproduction code-metabolism code-reproduction all-code ] 

patches-own [ turtle-count ]

to setup
  clear-all
  let list1 ( list 2 4 8 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 15 )  
  let n 2 ;; 20 meters away each turtle will be from another turtle
  set AvailablePatch patches with [ ( pxcor mod ( n + 1 ) = 0 ) and ( pycor mod ( n + 1 ) = 0 )  ]
  ask AvailablePatch
  [
    sprout 1
          [    
            set metabolism item 0 ( n-of 1 list1 )
            set reproduction item 0 ( n-of 1 list2 )
            setup-turtles who  
    ]
    set turtle-count ( turtle-count + 1 )
  ]
end
  

to setup-turtles [ whichTurtle? ]   
  ask turtle who [     
    (
      ifelse
      metabolism = 2 [
        set code-metabolism "M1"
        (
          ifelse
          reproduction = 5 [
            set code-reproduction "R1"
          ]
          reproduction = 10 [
            set code-reproduction "R2"
          ]
          reproduction = 15 [
            set code-reproduction "R3"
          ]
        )
      ]
      
      metabolism = 4 [ 
        set code-metabolism "M2"
        (
          ifelse
          reproduction = 5 [
            set code-reproduction "R1"
          ]
          reproduction = 10 [
            set code-reproduction "R2"
          ]
          reproduction = 15 [
            set code-reproduction "R3"
          ]
        )
      ]
      
      metabolism = 8 [ 
        set code-metabolism "M3"
        (
          ifelse
          reproduction = 5 [
            set code-reproduction "R1"
          ]
          reproduction = 10 [
            set code-reproduction "R2"
          ]
          reproduction = 15 [
            set code-reproduction "R3"
          ]
        )
      ]
    )
    set all-code ( word code-metabolism code-reproduction )
  ]
end
```

Comment: With the code above, you create a regular pattern of turtles, with default world-setting it's 121 turtles. 121 / 9=13.444444444444445. So you can't equally distribute the profiles, unless you change the worldsize or you don't let every `AvailablePatch` sprout a turtle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do, is to:

1. use 2 `foreach` loops. That way, you get all combinations of listitems:

```
  let list1 ( list 2 4 8 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 15 ) 
  foreach list1 
  [
    this_metabolism  ->
    foreach list2
    [
      this_reproduction  ->
      show word this_metabolism this_reproduction
      ;... other procedures
    ]
  ]
```

2. Now you want to create a turtle (or more) for each of this combinations, but only on a `AvailablePatch`:

```
ask one-of AvailablePatch
        [
          sprout 1
          [ 
            set metabolism this_metabolism
            set reproduction this_reproduction   
            setup-turtle 
          ]
          set turtle-count turtles-here
          set AvailablePatch other AvailablePatch ;this patch is no longer available
        ]
```

If you want more than one turtle per combination, instead of `ask one-of AvailablePatch` use for example `ask n-of 3 AvailablePatch`.

I changed some more things on your code:

1. there is a reporter, that reports an agentset containing all the turtles on the patch `set turtle-count count turtles-here`. You don't even have to update it there, but just call `count turtles-here` instead of `turtle-count`, when you need it. That way you don't have to add and substract turtles everytime you create new ones or some die.
2. inside `sprout` its already "turtle code". Meaning that you don't have to call the procedure with a turtle's `who` number, but you can write the code as it was inside an `ask turtle [...]` block.
3. the `ifelse` cases inside `setup-turtles` are independed, so it can be simplified.

Full code:

```
globals [ AvailablePatch ]

turtles-own [ metabolism reproduction code-metabolism code-reproduction all-code ] 

patches-own [ turtle-count ]

to setup
  clear-all
  let list1 ( list 2 4 8 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 15 )  
  let n 2 ;; 20 meters away each turtle will be from another turtle
  
  set AvailablePatch patches with [ ( pxcor mod ( n + 1 ) = 0 ) and ( pycor mod ( n + 1 ) = 0 )  ]
  (
    foreach list1 
    [
      this_metabolism  ->
      
      foreach list2
      [
        this_reproduction  ->
        ask one-of AvailablePatch
        [
          sprout 1
          [ 
            set metabolism this_metabolism
            set reproduction this_reproduction   
            setup-turtle 
          ]
          set turtle-count count turtles-here
          set AvailablePatch other AvailablePatch
        ]      
      ]
    ]
  )
end


to setup-turtle   ;turtle procedure
  (
    ifelse
    metabolism = 2 [set code-metabolism "M1"]      
    metabolism = 4 [set code-metabolism "M2"]      
    metabolism = 8 [set code-metabolism "M3"]
  )
  (
    ifelse
    reproduction = 5 [set code-reproduction "R1"]
    reproduction = 10 [set code-reproduction "R2"]
    reproduction = 15 [set code-reproduction "R3"]
  )
  set all-code ( word code-metabolism code-reproduction )
  set color reproduction
  set pcolor metabolism
end
```

Comment: Hi Lena, Thank you so much for your help :) But, I still couldn't solve my problem. Well, I wasn't very precise with my question. But, it helped to solve a part. Could you see my new post with my question, but clarified (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760978/how-to-make-an-equitable-distribution-of-turtles-using-netlogo-6-2)? And if you can help me, I'll be very grateful :)