# How to make an equitable distribution of turtles using NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem that I asked for help here: [How to make an equal distribution of turtles for each profile type using NetLogo 6.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70748349/how-to-make-an-equal-distribution-of-turtles-for-each-profile-type-using-netlogo)

And Lena helped me a lot :)

But, I was not very precise in what I would like and it was partially solved. I tried to adjust how Lena responded and I couldn't, because I get stuck in the very similar problem that I still don't understand how to deal in the code.

So my problem is the following:

I have 31 profiles of turtles that refer to combinations of 5 types of habitats. For example:

```
profile1: turtles are only born in habitat 1
profile2: turtles are only born in habitat 2
profile3: turtles are only born in habitat 3
profile4: turtles are only born in habitat 4
profile5: turtles are only born in habitat 5
profile6: turtles are only born in habitats 1 and 2
profile6: turtles are only born in habitats 1 and 3
... until you reach profile 31 where the turtles are born in habitats 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5
```

The problem is that I have 2 more variables (metabolism (M) and reproduction (R)), each with 3 levels:

```
M1R1
M1R2
M1R3
M2R1
M2R2
M2R3
M3R1
M3R2
M3R3
```

I would like to have exactly these nine combinations for the 31 turtle profiles. For example:

```
Perfil1 (turtles are only born in habitat 1):
M1R1
M1R2
M1R3
M2R1
M2R2
M2R3
M3R1
M3R2
M3R3

Perfil2 (turtles are only born in habitat 2): 
M1R1
M1R2
M1R3
M2R1
M2R2
M2R3
M3R1
M3R2
M3R3

... until you reach profile 31 where the turtles are born in habitats 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5:
M1R1
M1R2
M1R3
M2R1
M2R2
M2R3
M3R1
M3R2
M3R3
```

The issue is that I get the following return:

```
profile21: M1R1
profile17: M1R2
profile20: M1R3
profile17: M2R1
profile6: M2R2
profile26: M2R3
profile30: M3R1
profile7: M3R2
profile27: M3R3
```

But what I would like is to have this combination of metabolism and reproduction variables for each of the 31 profiles. Like for example:

```
profile1: M1R1
profile1: M1R2
profile1: M1R3
profile1: M2R1
profile1: M2R2
profile1: M2R3
profile1: M3R1
profile1: M3R2
profile1: M3R3

profile2: M1R1
profile2: M1R2
profile2: M1R3
profile2: M2R1
profile2: M2R2
profile2: M2R3
profile2: M3R1
profile2: M3R2
profile2: M3R3

... until you reach profile 31 
profile31: M1R1
profile31: M1R2
profile31: M1R3
profile31: M2R1
profile31: M2R2
profile31: M2R3
profile31: M3R1
profile31: M3R2
profile31: M3R3
```

Could anyone help me understand how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance :)

The code, below:

```
globals [ AvailablePatch UnassignedProfileCountList ValidHabs ]

turtles-own [ metabolism reproduction code-metabolism code-reproduction all-code  turtle-profiles-habitat ]

patches-own [ turtle-count habitatcover ]


to setup
  clear-all
  random-seed 1  
  resize-world 69 * 0 ( 69 * 1 )  ( 69 * -1 ) 69 * 0 
  read
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
  foreach sort turtles
                  [
                    t ->
                    ask t
                    [
                      print ( word "I am turtle:" " " who " "  "my profile type:" " " turtle-profiles-habitat " " "my code:" " " all-code " " "my code reproduction level:" " " code-reproduction " " "my code metabolism level:" " " code-metabolism )
                    ]
  ]
end

to read  
  set ValidHabs [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 ]  
end


    
to-report get-any-incomplete-profile [ habtype ]
  let kkk 0
  let shortlist [ ]
  let validhablist [];

  repeat 30
  [
    set kkk ( kkk  + 1 ) 
    set validhablist item kkk ValidHabs
    
    if (
      (( item kkk UnassignedProfileCountList > 0 ) and (  true =  member? habtype validhablist ))
    )
    [
      set shortlist lput kkk shortlist
     
    ]
  ]

  let mypick -1
 
  ifelse ( 0 < length shortlist )
      [
        set mypick  item 0 (  n-of 1 shortlist )
        

        let oldcount item mypick UnassignedProfileCountList
        let newcount ( oldcount - 1 )
        set UnassignedProfileCountList replace-item mypick UnassignedProfileCountList newcount
  ]
  [
    set mypick -1
  ]
  report mypick
end


to setup-patches 

  let n 2 
  set AvailablePatch patches with [
    ( pxcor mod ( n + 1 ) = 0 ) and ( pycor mod ( n + 1 ) = 0 )   ]
  set UnassignedProfileCountList [ 0 ]  
  repeat 30 
  [
    set UnassignedProfileCountList lput 9 UnassignedProfileCountList
  ]

  let list1 ( list 2 4 8 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 15 )

  (
    foreach list1
    [
      this-metabolism ->

      foreach list2
      [
        this-reproduction ->

        ask one-of AvailablePatch           
            [
              sprout 1
              [
                set turtle-profiles-habitat oneprofile
                set metabolism this-metabolism
                set reproduction this-reproduction

                setup-turtles
              ]
              set turtle-count count turtles-here
              set AvailablePatch other AvailablePatch 
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  )
end


to setup-turtles   
   (
    ifelse
    metabolism = 2 [set code-metabolism "M1"]      
    metabolism = 4 [set code-metabolism "M2"]      
    metabolism = 8 [set code-metabolism "M3"]
  )
  (
    ifelse
    reproduction = 5 [set code-reproduction "R1"]
    reproduction = 10 [set code-reproduction "R2"]
    reproduction = 15 [set code-reproduction "R3"]
  )
  set all-code ( word code-metabolism code-reproduction )
  set color reproduction
  set pcolor metabolism
end
```

Comment: What function or reporter returns the unwanted result? Where in your code do you combine the profile with the metabolism and reproduction?

Comment: Hi Lena, I think I put what you asked for. I edited the code above! Thanks in advance! Any help would be most welcome :)

Comment: Hi Rafaela, I still can't reproduce the result. When I run the code, you provide, I get an error, because the list `ValidHabs` is not created.
It would be nice, if you checked that code you provide has the same behavior as your full code - just open an empty model and insert the code above. Here is a short manual on how to create a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Lena,
Sorry for the mistake again. Yesterday, I tweaked the code, but I couldn't understand how I could upload .csv and .asc files for you to run the code. And then I sent it without the files. But, with the need to reproduce the problem, I spent the night trying to adapt the code so that I don't need to upload files and so you can reproduce my problem. And now it's doing that :) I've tweaked the code and the question. If you can help me I would be very grateful :)

Comment: If someone from the community, too, can help! I appreciate it :)

Comment: That looks like a lot of work you put into the read function! Just setting `ValidHabitats` to a list with fixed values would have been enough.

Comment: Really Lena, I hadn't thought of that! I've tweaked the code to be smaller and more understandable. Once more, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, you have a list and want to create a specific number of turtles for each combination of this list with the other lists. So, you can use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ValidHabs [
  this-profile ->
  ;code that should be run for every entry of ValidHabs
]
```

The whole setup-patches function:

```
to setup-patches 
  
  let n 2 ;; 20 meters away each turtle will be from another turtle
  set AvailablePatch patches with [
    ( pxcor mod ( n + 1 ) = 0 ) and ( pycor mod ( n + 1 ) = 0 )   ]
  set UnassignedProfileCountList [ 0 ]  ;; effectively start from item 1 not zero
  repeat 30 
  [
    set UnassignedProfileCountList lput 9 UnassignedProfileCountList
  ]
  
  let list1 ( list 2 4 8 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 15 )
  
  (
    foreach ValidHabs [
      this-profile ->
      
      foreach list1
      [
        this-metabolism ->
        
        foreach list2
        [
          this-reproduction ->
          
          ask one-of AvailablePatch
          [ 
            sprout 1
            [
              set turtle-profiles-habitat this-profile
              set metabolism this-metabolism
              set reproduction this-reproduction
              
              setup-turtles
            ]
            set turtle-count count turtles-here
            set AvailablePatch other AvailablePatch ;this patch is no longer available
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  )
end
```