# How can I use foreach inside a code in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo and I'm having a hard time understanding the logic of using foreach and joining two parts into a single code. Can anyone help me understand and solve my problem?

My problem:

I have 31 profiles of turtles that refer to combinations of 5 types of habitats. For example:

```
profile1: turtles are only born in habitat 1
profile2: turtles are only born in habitat 2
profile3: turtles are only born in habitat 3
profile4: turtles are only born in habitat 4
profile5: turtles are only born in habitat 5
profile6: turtles are only born in habitats 1 and 2
profile7: turtles are only born in habitats 1 and 3
... until you reach profile31 where the turtles are born in habitats 1, 2, 3, 4 an 5
```

I also have 2 variables with 3 levels each. The reproduction variable (R) and the metabolism variable (M), which results in 9 combinations, that is:

```
R1M1
R1M2
R1M3

R2M1
R2M2
R2M3

R3M1
R3M2
R3M3
```

I would like to have these 9 combinations for each of the 31 turtle profiles. For example:

Profile1:

```
R1M1
R1M2
R1M3

R2M1
R2M2
R2M3

R3M1
R3M2
R3M3
```

Profile2:

```
R1M1
R1M2
R1M3

R2M1
R2M2
R2M3

R3M1
R3M2
R3M3
```

And so on until you reach profile 31 having these 9 levels (
combinations of the 3 levels of the variables reproduction (R) and metabolism (M)). And therefore, generating 279 turtles in the world (31 profiles * 9 = 279)

I had help on this link: [How to make an equitable distribution of turtles using NetLogo 6.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760978/how-to-make-an-equitable-distribution-of-turtles-using-netlogo-6-2) and thank you very much

However, I'm not able to understand the logic and put two pieces of code to work together. I have this part of the code that has to exist for the following code structure to work:

```
 ask AvailablePatch
  [ let oneprofile 99 ;;dummy value
    while [ ( count turtles-here < 1 ) and ( sum UnassignedProfileCountList > 0 ) and ( oneprofile > 0 ) ]  
          [
            set oneprofile get-any-incomplete-profile habitatcover
            if ( oneprofile > 0 )
            [
              sprout 1
              [
                set turtle-profiles-habitat oneprofile
                
                
                set metabolism item 0 ( n-of 1 list1 )
                set reproduction item 0 ( n-of 1 list2 )
                
                
                setup-turtles who
              ]
              set turtle-count ( turtle-count + 1 )
            ]     
    ]
  ]
```

I know that the lines of code below make it not generate the 9 equal combinations for each profile

```
set metabolism item 0 ( n-of 1 list1 )
set reproduction item 0 ( n-of 1 list2 )
```

For example, 9 turtles were born for each profile, but with repetitions or unbalanced. For example:

Profile1:

```
R1M3
R1M3
R1M3
R1M3
    
R2M2
    
R3M2
R3M3
R3M3
R3M1
```

And I want for each of the 31 turtle profiles to have 9 balanced combinations without repetitions. For example:

Profile1:

```
R1M1
R1M2
R1M3

R2M1
R2M2
R2M3

R3M1
R3M2
R3M3
```

I know that using foreach I could get the 9 desired combinations. Using the code below:

```
(
 foreach list1
 [
 this_metabolism ->

 foreach list2
 [
 this_reproduction ->
 ask one-of AvailablePatch
 [
 sprout 1
 [
 set metabolism this_metabolism
 set reproduction this_reproduction
 setup-turtles who
 ]
 set turtle-count count turtles-here
 set AvailablePatch other AvailablePatch
 ]
 ]
 ]
 )
```

But trying to merge this foreach code (above) with the general structure of the code doesn't work. I've put it in all the positions I thought would be somewhat logical. And it just doesn't work.

Can someone explain to me how I could put these two pieces of code together?

Thanks in advance :)

The complete code, below:

```
globals [ AvailablePatch UnassignedProfileCountList ValidHabs ]

turtles-own [ metabolism reproduction code-metabolism code-reproduction all-code  turtle-profiles-habitat ]

patches-own [ turtle-count habitatcover ]


to setup
  clear-all
  random-seed 1      
  read
  setup-world
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
  foreach sort turtles
                  [
                    t ->
                    ask t
                    [
                      print ( word "I am turtle:" " " who " "  "my profile type:" " " turtle-profiles-habitat " "  "my code reproduction level:" " " code-reproduction " " "my code metabolism level:" " " code-metabolism )
                    ]
  ]
end

to read
  set ValidHabs [ [ 0 0 0 0 0 ] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [3 4] [3 5] [4 5] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 2 5] [1 3 4] [1 3 5] [1 4 5] [2 3 4] [2 3 5] [2 4 5] [3 4 5] [1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 5] [1 2 4 5] [1 3 4 5] [2 3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5]]
end


to setup-world
  let pcolors []
  set pcolors [ 25 65 23 53 105 ]
  ask patches [
    set pcolor item (random 5) pcolors
  ]

  ask patches [
    if pcolor = 25 [ set habitatcover 1 ]
    if pcolor = 65 [ set habitatcover 2 ]
    if pcolor = 23 [ set habitatcover 3 ]
    if pcolor = 53 [ set habitatcover 4 ]
    if pcolor = 105 [ set habitatcover 5 ]
  ]
end

to-report get-any-incomplete-profile [ habtype ]      
  let kkk 0
  let shortlist [ ]
  let validhablist [];

  repeat 31
  [
    set kkk ( kkk  + 1 ) 
    set validhablist item kkk ValidHabs
    
    if (
      (( item kkk UnassignedProfileCountList > 0 ) and (  true =  member? habtype validhablist ))
    )
    [
      set shortlist lput kkk shortlist          
    ]
  ]

  let mypick -1      
  ifelse ( 0 < length shortlist )
      [
        set mypick  item 0 (  n-of 1 shortlist )
        ;; print ( word "mypick is " mypick )

        let oldcount item mypick UnassignedProfileCountList
        let newcount ( oldcount - 1 )
        set UnassignedProfileCountList replace-item mypick UnassignedProfileCountList newcount
  ]
  [
    set mypick -1
  ]
  report mypick
end


to setup-patches
  set AvailablePatch patches with [
    ( pxcor mod ( 2 + 1 ) = 0 ) and ( pycor mod ( 2 + 1 ) = 0 )   ]
  set UnassignedProfileCountList [ 0 ]  ;; effectively start from item 1 not zero
  repeat 31
  [
    set UnassignedProfileCountList lput 9 UnassignedProfileCountList
  ]
  
  let list1 ( list 2 4 8 )
  let list2 ( list 5 10 15 )
  
  
   (
 foreach list1
 [
 this_metabolism ->

 foreach list2
 [
 this_reproduction ->
 ask one-of AvailablePatch
 [
 sprout 1
 [
 set metabolism this_metabolism
 set reproduction this_reproduction
 setup-turtles
 ]
 set turtle-count count turtles-here
 set AvailablePatch other AvailablePatch
 ]
 ]
 ]
 )  

end


to setup-turtles 
  ask turtle who  [    
    (
      ifelse
      metabolism = 2 [set code-metabolism "M1"]
      metabolism = 4 [set code-metabolism "M2"]
      metabolism = 8 [set code-metabolism "M3"]
    )
    (
      ifelse
      reproduction = 5 [set code-reproduction "R1"]
      reproduction = 10 [set code-reproduction "R2"]
      reproduction = 15 [set code-reproduction "R3"]
    )
    set all-code ( word code-metabolism code-reproduction )
  ]
end
```

Comment: What is the difference between profile 1 and profile 2?

Comment: The difference is that profile1 can only be born in habitat type 1. Profile2 can only be born in type 2 habitat. Profiles are combinations of 5 types of habitats and will give 31 profiles. A list with 31 items: [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [ 3 4] [3 5] [4 5] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 2 5] [1 3 4] [1 3 5] [1 4 5] [2 3 4] [2 3 5 ] [2 4 5] [3 4 5] [1 2 3 4] [1 2 3 5] [1 2 4 5] [1 3 4 5] [2 3 4 5] [1 2 3 4 5]]

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is- in the first example above the values for both profiles (after you say "I would like to have these 9 combinations...") appear to be identical. Am I misreading that, or is it intentional?

Comment: Yes it is intentional. I would like to have these 9 identical combinations for each of the 31 profiles. then profile1 will have these 9 combinations (of variables R and M) as well as profile2, profile3, profile4... until reaching profile31. Here what will change is the profile but the 9 combinations are identical for all 31 profiles. Is it better to understand? Thanks :)

Comment: What's wrong with the code, I gave you in the other answer? Here, you didn't fully copy it and left out the `foreach` loop for the `ValidHabs`. What doesn't work, when you copy all of the procedure from the other question instead of your procedure and write `to setup-turtles` without  `[ wichTurtle? ] `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create turtles with all profile and R and M combinations, but also let the patches, the turtles get placed on be `one-of` the turtles `profile`, you can just reassign the patch's `habitatcover`. They are chosen randomly before, so it doesn't change anything about the randomness.

Just add

```
ask one-of AvailablePatch
          [ 
            set habitatcover one-of this-profile
            if habitatcover = 1 [set pcolor 25]
            if habitatcover = 2 [set pcolor 65]
            if habitatcover = 3 [set pcolor 23]
            if habitatcover = 4 [set pcolor 53]
            if habitatcover = 5 [set pcolor 105]
            
            ;...
          ]
```

to the code I gave you in the other answer.

Comment: You can check, if the assignment worked, by adding `ask turtles [if (not member? habitatcover turtle-profiles-habitat)
                      [
                        print  ( word "habitatcover:" " " habitatcover " "  "my profile type:" " " turtle-profiles-habitat)
                      ]]`
to the `setup` procedure. It would print the info only, if a turtle is on a patch, that is not one of the turtle's habitat.

Comment: Thanks so much :) I am very happy. Now I think I understand :)